# How to create a method common to other classes

Tags: c#, winforms

IDE:

- VS 2010
- C#
- .net winforms application

I have 5 winforms. and I have a method

```
clearTextBoxes(textboxes[] tb)
{
  //Code for clearing text boxes
}
```

Now instead of copying this code in each class i want to call this method from a common class. but I am not getting how to perform this.

One way I think is by making it a static method But can u suggest me any other better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
public class MyCommonClass
{
    public static void ClearTextBoxes(TextBoxes[] tb)
    {
        if (tb != null)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < tb.Count; i++)
                tb[i].Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

and call from various forms as

```
MyCommonClass.ClearTextBoxes(myTextBoxesArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily better than a static method in a common class, but if you only plan to use it only in froms, a different way of doing this would be creating a parent form class that contains this method and use it as a base class.

```
public class ParentForm : Form
{
    public void ClearTextBoxes(textboxes[] tb)
    {
        //Code for clearing text boxes
    }
}
public class MyForm : ParentForm
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        //More code
        clearTextBoxes(textboxes[] tb);
    }
}
```

[Base (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx)